# C Language: Error in Freeing members of struct in an a function

Tags: c, struct, malloc, structure, free

I have a a pointer to a struct, and trying to free the memory in a common function. So I am sending a pointer to this pointer to my destroy function as per the code below. 
Initially I want to de-allocate the char* members of the stuct and then the structure itself. 
It is giving me `Bus error (core dumped)` when I try to free the members but it is OK with freeing structure alone!. 
Note: I added printf and I can see that I can print the string inside. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
   const size_t name_size = 50;
   typedef struct Student{
        int id;
        char * firstname;
        char * surname;
    } Student; 


    Student* createStudent(void);
    void destroyStudent(Student**);

    int main(){
        Student * student = createStudent();
        student->firstname = "My_firstname";
        student->surname = "My_lastname";
        student->id = 2;
        destroyStudent(&student);
    }

    Student* createStudent(){
        Student * studentPtr = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student));
        studentPtr->firstname = (char *) malloc(name_size);
        studentPtr->surname = (char *) malloc(name_size);
        return studentPtr;
    }

    void destroyStudent(Student** ptr){
        printf("%s\n", (*ptr)->firstname);
        printf("%s\n", (*ptr)->surname);
        free((*ptr)->firstname);
        free((*ptr)->surname);
        free(*ptr);
        *ptr = NULL;
    }
```

Output

```
My_firstname
My_lastname
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Comment: You are freeing student->firstname and student->surname, even though they are not malloc'ed

Comment: If you want them to be dynamically allocated, you can use `student->firstname = strdup("whatever");`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the createStudent function which does the malloc
Updated the code... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save the pointers from `malloc` here

```
    studentPtr->firstname = (char *) malloc(name_size);
    studentPtr->surname = (char *) malloc(name_size);
```

You overwrite the pointers here

```
    student->firstname = "My_firstname";
    student->surname = "My_lastname";
```

When you try to free the overwritten pointers, you are trying to free pointers that were not returned by `malloc`.

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
    strncpy(student->firstname, "My_firstname", name_size);
    strncpy(student->surname, "My_lastname", name_size);
```

Comment: you're right, got it and problem solved. Thanks so much